# Jersey jax-rs client proxy doesn't marshall object when doing a POST

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm trying to use the jersey client proxy for doing a POST to an endpoint, but the object that I send in doesn't get marshalled into json.

The interface looks like this:

```
public interface Authentication {

@POST
@Path("principal")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
ApiPrincipal principal(@BeanParam ApiAuthenticationRequest authRequest, @HeaderParam("x-forwarded-for") String forwardedFor, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws UserError;

}
```

The client code looks like this:

```
ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig()
        .register(JacksonFeature.class)
        .register(new Authenticator(remoteUser, password));
Client resource = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);

Authentication a = WebResourceFactory.newResource(Authentication.class,
    resource.target(scheme + "://" + remoteHost + ":" + port + "/app/api/authentication/v-1/"));

ApiAuthenticationRequest authRequest = new ApiAuthenticationRequest();
authRequest.username = username;
authRequest.remoteIp = "localhost";
a.principal(authRequest, null, null);
```

If I look at the request in wireshark everything looks fine, except that it doesn't have a body.

my dependencies are these (jersey version 2.22.1):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-proxy-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: First thing you should do is get rid of the `@BeanParam`. That shouldn't have affect on the data being sent though.

Comment: Other than that, not sure what you're doing wrong. You can check out this [gist with a complete runnable example](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/05c29f22990f9e5bf62c). See if you can build on it to try and reproduce your problem. Maybe you can narrow down the cause

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for the example, it works fine for me also, but if I add a Context HttpServletRequest request to the interface it breaks, see here https://gist.github.com/alexanderkjall/e63711d00f78091b80d3 I'll report this as a Jersey bug.

Comment: Another datapoint is that if I flip the order of Model and HttpServletRequest it starts to work.

Comment: Yeah, you're right on both accounts. Odd. Also doesn't seem related to the issue, but [here](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/2b5bc1058d29e5e10125) is the correct way to deploy the test in a servlet environment. The previous version would always give you a null servlet request, as it is not configured as a servlet env.

Comment: Looking at the source for [`WebResourceFactory`](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/2b5bc1058d29e5e10125), it does look like a bug. It loops through all the parameters (really their annotations), and if you look at line 213, it checks to see if it has any `@XxxParam` annotations. If not, it determined the parameter is the entity body. But this is true for both the Model _and_ the HttpServletRequest, so the last of the two will always be the entity body argument. In the case HttpServletRequest is the entity body, you pass null.

Comment: The only problem with this bug, is that should they include `@Context` in the checked annotations? What about all other custom annotations? I would maybe suggest an overload method that accepts an entity index. That's probably the easiest fix for them. Or just document that the entity should always be the last parameter :-)

Comment: I'd the same problem and removing the "BeanParam" as pointed out by @peeskillet solved it!